# Site names are showing wrongly in Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll in C#?

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am trying to get the **Site names which are available in IIS 7** using the following code;

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var sites = serverManager.Sites;
    foreach (Site site in sites)
    {
        ret.Add(site.Name);                                                            
    }
}
```

On my PC, site names which are available in IIS 7 are showing exactly, but when I try to run that exe in my colleague PC,**Site names are showing wrongly.**

For example: On my colleague PC, he actually having 2 websites like

1. Default Web Site
2. Hello.

But when I run that exe, more than two websites are showing like `default website`, `hello`, `hellouser123`, `hellouser`, `sampleapp` and so and so.

I don't know what is the problem.

Can you guide me?

Comment: The code above is correct and it will work exactly the same way in every IIS machine adding to the list the name of the sites that are configured in the machine. Maybe you can clarify what your intent is since that is correct. The only other option I can think of is that you are referencing the wrong Microsoft.Web.Administration using the IIS Express version instead of the "%windir%\system32\inetsrv"

Answer (score 0):

The code will return a list of site names **for the machine that is running the code.** If your colleague runs the code, it will list the IIS website names on *his/her* computer, not yours, so the site names may be different depending on how you each have your IIS sites set up.

If you want to display a list of sites on one particular IIS instance, you need to tell the code to connect to a specific IIS instance on a specific machine. You can use [`ServerManager.OpenRemote()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do this.